# Добавление строки в pandas по сопоставлению дат

Tags: python, pandas

Датафрейм 1:

1. 2012-04-30  **-0.573932**
2. 2012-05-01  **0.254934**
3. 2012-05-02  **0.138534**
4. 2012-05-03  **1.275097**

Датафрейм 2:

1. 2012-05-01  **0.246099**
2. 2012-05-02  **-0.133284**
3. 2012-05-04  **0.649255**
4. 2012-06-04  **0.779903**

Хочу получить датафрейм 3, так что если даты 1 и 2 совпадающие есть, то они складываются, если нет то значения из каждого датафрейма, вот так:

1. 2012-04-30  **-0.573932**
2. 2012-05-01  **(0.254934 + 0.246099)**
3. 2012-05-02  **(0.138534 - 0.133284)**
4. 2012-05-03  **1.275097**
5. 2012-05-04  **0.649255**
6. 2012-06-04  **0.779903**

Не подскажите как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Соединить датафреймы через `pd.concat`
2. Сделать группировку с суммированием `df.groupby('date').sum().reset_index()`

Comment: Благодарю! Помогло!